Wirtinger derivatives in 3D vector space
I am trying to apply the calculations from Wirtinger derivatives on a real plane to 3D space.
We know the quaternions play the role of complex numbers in 3D, and a 3D vector cannot be separated from the trivector component.
Let us use the following notations for quaternions and the dual four-vectors:
$\left\langle \begin{array}{c} x\\y\\z\\t \end{array} \right\rangle \equiv x\vec{j}\vec{k} + y\vec{k}\vec{i} + z\vec{i}\vec{j} + t$,
$\left[\begin{array}{c} x\\y\\z\\t \end{array}\right] \equiv x\vec{i} + y\vec{j} + z\vec{k} + tI$,
where $I \equiv \vec{i}\vec{j}\vec{k}$
in an orthonormal basis $(\vec{i}, \vec{j}, \vec{k})$.
The differential of a four-vector $r$: $dr = dx\vec{i} + dy\vec{j} + dz\vec{k} + dtI$.
We want to add three more components to resolve the system against $dx$, $dy$, $dz$, and $dt$.
A 3D movement cannot produce a mirrored object, so we can define the three components as:
$\begin{cases}
 dr_x = -dx\vec{i} + dy\vec{j} + dz\vec{k} + dtI \\
 dr_y = \phantom -dx\vec{i} - dy\vec{j} + dz\vec{k} + dtI \\
 dr_z = \phantom -dx\vec{i} + dy\vec{j} - dz\vec{k} + dtI \\
\end{cases}$.
Applying the GA vector multiplication rules: $\begin{cases}
 dx = \frac{\vec{i}}{2}\left(dr-dr_x\right) \\
 dy = \frac{\vec{j}}{2}\left(dr-dr_y\right) \\
 dz = \frac{\vec{k}}{2}\left(dr-dr_z\right) \\
 dt = \frac{I}{2}\left(dr-dr_x-dr_y-dr_z\right)\\
\end{cases}$.
Let $f$ be a four-vector function: $f = \left[\begin{array}{c}u(x,y,z,t)\\v(x,y,z,t)\\w(x,y,z,t)\\\theta(x,y,z,t)\end{array}\right]$.
The differential of $f$: $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt$.
Substituting $dx$, $dy$, $dz$, and $dt$:
$\small df = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec{i} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vec{j} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\vec{k} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}I\right)dr + \frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec{i} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}I\right)dr_x+\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vec{j} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}I\right)dr_y+\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\vec{k} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}I\right)dr_z.$
$df = \left(\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_x}\\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_y}\\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_z}\\
\end{array}\right)^T
\left(\begin{array}{c}dr\\dr_x\\dr_y\\dr_z\\\end{array}\right) \Rightarrow \left(\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_x}\\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_y}\\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_z}\\
\end{array}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec{i} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vec{j} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\vec{k} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}I\\
 -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec{i} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}I\\
 -\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vec{j} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}I\\
 -\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\vec{k} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}I\\
\end{array}\right)$.
Substituting
$\begin{cases}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\vec{i} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\vec{j}
 + \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\vec{k} + \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}I\\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\vec{i} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\vec{j}
 + \frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\vec{k} + \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}I\\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\vec{i} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial z}\vec{j}
 + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\vec{k} + \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial z}I\\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\vec{i} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\vec{j}
 + \frac{\partial w}{\partial t}\vec{k}+\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}I\\
\end{cases}$, obtaining $\left(\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_x}\\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_y}\\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_z}\\
\end{array}\right)
= $
$\small \frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
 \left(\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)\vec{j}\vec{k} + \left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\right)\vec{k}\vec{i} + \left(-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial t}\right)\vec{i}\vec{j} + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}\right)\\
 \left(-\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)\vec{j}\vec{k} + \left(-\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\right)\vec{k}\vec{i} + \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}\right)\vec{i}\vec{j} + \left(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}\right)\\
 \left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)\vec{j}\vec{k}+\left(-\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\right)\vec{k}\vec{i} + \left(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial w}{\partial t}\right)\vec{i}\vec{j} + \left(-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}\right)\\
 \left(-\frac{\partial v}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)\vec{j}\vec{k} + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\right)\vec{k}\vec{i} + \left(-\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial w}{\partial t}\right)\vec{i}\vec{j} + \left(-\frac{\partial w}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}\right)\\
\end{array}\right)$
By the choice of $r_x$, $r_y$, and $r_z$: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r_x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_z} = 0$, therefore
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{2}\left\langle\begin{array}{r}
 \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\\
 \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\\
 -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial t}\\
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}\\
\end{array}\right\rangle$,
where $\begin{cases}
 \phantom -\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}\\
 \phantom -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}\\
 -\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\\
 -\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\\
\end{cases}$
Now, we have multiple ways of substituting the partial derivatives of $u$, $v$, $w$, $\theta$ in the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$.
Let us first try to generalize the previous 2D result.
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{\partial w}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial z}\right)\vec{j}\vec{k} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right)\vec{k}\vec{i} + \frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\vec{i}\vec{j}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}$.
With the standard 3D notations
$\vec{f} \equiv \left[\begin{array}{c}u\\v\\w\\\end{array}\right]$ and
$\vec{\nabla} \equiv \left[\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
\end{array}\right]$:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{f}\right) - \frac{I}{2}\left[\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{f}\right] - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t},$$
or, in geometric product notation:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{\nabla}\vec{f}\right)^\ast-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}.$$
This seems to correlate with the previous 2D result.
However, we did not use all the restrictions on the partial derivatives of $u$, $v$, $w$, $\theta$ in here.
Applying all the conditions:
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left\langle\begin{array}{r}\theta\\w\\-v\\u\\\end{array}\right\rangle=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left\langle\begin{array}{r}-w\\\theta\\u\\v\\\end{array}\right\rangle=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left\langle\begin{array}{r}v\\-u\\\theta\\w\\\end{array}\right\rangle=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left\langle\begin{array}{r}-u\\-v\\-w\\\theta\\\end{array}\right\rangle$.
Using the GA vector multiplication we can write:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec{i}
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vec{j}
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\vec{k}
= -\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}I
= \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec{i}
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vec{j}
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\vec{k}
- \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}I\right).$$
Since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ are four-vectors, and they do not commute with $\vec{i}$, $\vec{j}$, and $\vec{k}$,
we cannot write it as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{4}\nabla f$,
where $\nabla \equiv \left[\begin{array}{r}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
 -\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\\
\end{array}\right]$, can we?
Alternatively:
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \left\langle\begin{array}{r}
 -\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\\
 -\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\\
\end{array}\right\rangle u = 
\left\langle\begin{array}{r}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
 -\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\\
 -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
\end{array}\right\rangle v =
\left\langle\begin{array}{r}
 -\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\\
 -\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
\end{array}\right\rangle w =
\left\langle\begin{array}{r}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\\
\end{array}\right\rangle \theta$,
or, applying GA vector multiplication:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \vec{i}\nabla u = \vec{j}\nabla v = \vec{k}\nabla w = I\nabla\theta = \frac{1}{4}\left(\vec{i}\nabla u+\vec{j}\nabla v + \vec{k}\nabla w + I\nabla\theta\right).$$
But those formulas are also confusing since $\nabla f_i$ are four-vectors too.
Instead, with the new notation
$\partial \equiv \left\langle\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\\
\end{array}\right\rangle = I\nabla = \nabla I$, from the last column we have:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=\partial\theta.$$
Questions:
Does it all make sense?
If yes, from the last formula it follows that any "physical" 3D vector function can be described with a single real-valued function $\theta(x,y,z,t)$.
Is this correct? Is this something we know and use in physics?
